# extract tabular data in pdf using pdfbox

Tags: java, scala, pdfbox

Can we extract tabular data in pdf  using pdfbox API. Using getText from PDFTextStripper is removing information like column to data mapping as there is lack of delimiter between data in each cell. Could you suggest a method

Comment: *"Using getText from PDFTextStripper is removing information like column to data mapping"* - unless you are talking about tagged pdfs, there is nothing like a *column to data mapping* in pdfs. All you have in pdfs usually is *text at coordinates*. `getText` drops the coordinates but you can override methods of the `PDFTextStripper` to retrieve text with coordinates. There have been many questions and answers on that here on stack overflow.

Comment: Try tabula http://tabula.technology/ this is on top of PDFBox.